# Not able to create a spec file for the controller in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am new to ROR. I am working on Rspec.. 
I have been provided with a full package of an application. 
I kept it in my rails dir. 
The dir itself contains  spec folder with some controllers/models and fixtures but without spec_helper file.
So when i run $spec spec/ i got an error

```
     /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rspec-1.3.0/lib/spec/runner/options.rb:283:in `files_to_load': File or directory not found: spec/ (RuntimeError)
```

So i simply deleted the whole spec folder. 
And again created  a new spec by

aruna@aruna-desktop:~/railsprojects/appname_c$ script/generate rspec
Configuring rspec and rspec-rails gems in config/environments/test.rb ...

```
  exists  lib/tasks
  create  lib/tasks/rspec.rake
  create  script/autospec
  create  script/spec
  create  spec
  create  spec/rcov.opts
  create  spec/spec.opts
  create  spec/spec_helper.rb
```

aruna@aruna-desktop:~/railsprojects/appname_c$

after all this .. I try to add the testing spec for my controller Users by

```
     aruna@aruna-desktop:~/railsprojects/appname_c$ script/generate rspec_controller Users new
     The name 'UsersController' is either already used in your application or reserved by Ruby on Rails.
     Please choose an alternative and run this generator again.
     aruna@aruna-desktop:~/railsprojects/appname_c$
```

I am getting the error as above .. 
Pls give me suggestions of why i am getting this error.
How to resolve this one..

Answer (score 1):

see [this thread](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/189286) on a similar topic. Something in your Rails environment may be defining `UsersController` before Rspec starts up.

Of course if you can't get the generator working, you can always just create the controller spec file yourself.

Comment: Ya i have created the Rspec file for the COntroller file instead of using script/generate for creating Rspec file ..